# Issue Uploading file to AWS S3 Bucket using Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Please excuse me, as there are already many questions on the same topic.

First some background: I started working on a Laravel 9 web application few months ago, created AWS S3 buckets and an IAM user with full access to AmazonS3, and used the user's access credentials in .env file. And I was able to upload files to the specified bucket, and was able to access the uploaded files in my web application.

Last week, I worked on SMTP setup for sending emails and made some changes to the .env file (though I am sure that I did not change the AWS settings). Now I notice that the uploading files to the AWS S3 bucket is failing with the message:

```
  exception: "League\\Flysystem\\UnableToWriteFile"
  file:"/var/www/vhosts/silkweb.ca/vendor/league/flysystem/src/UnableToWriteFile.php"
  line: 24
   message: "Unable to write file at location: user/profile/3/P2jFdBHTE49mxym6jxa4LHTAPvV0qDiFZ9SsYtZt.png. Error executing \"PutObject\"
```

I use the following commands to put the file in the AWS S3 bucket:

```
 $filepath = "/user/profile/".$user_id;  
 $upload_path =  Storage::disk('s3')->put($filepath, $request->file('file'));
```

I even created a new IAM user and used that user's credentials in my .env file, but still no luck. My current .env settings for AWS are as follows

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKI***************DAY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=jotz*************************ru
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
AWS_BUCKET=silkweb
AWS_URL=silkweb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://silkweb-s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

I have used php artisan clear:cache and php artisan config:clear several times.

Any idea, why I am not able to create a file in the AWS S3 bucket?

Comment: There is a typo in your endpoint, "amazozaws" should be "amazonaws", can you try that

Comment: @omuthu, that did not fix the issue, as ENDPOINT is not used.

Answer (score 0):

After I commented the AWS_URL and AWS_ENDPOINT, file upload started working. The following are the working settings

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKI***********DG
 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=l36***************0C
 AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
 AWS_BUCKET=silkweb
 AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
 AWS_S3_SILKWEB_URL="https://silkweb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
 **#AWS_URL=silkweb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com**
 **#AWS_ENDPOINT=http://silkweb-s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com**
```